# Help me with this "왜"

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase-meaning

If after "왜" there is a comma, is the meaning still "why?", because I found some sentences that makes me confused.
For example, I found this sentence :
남서부에서 산사태도 발생했다던데. 왜, 그 무슨 백작 부인도 거기 휘말려서...

There's "왜" but that's not a 'question' , right?

Comment: That 왜 is an exclamation (감탄사) you use when something does not occur to your mind at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly the same as using "why" with a coma; that is, why used as an interjection.

왜, 그 있잖아, 코 큰 사람.

Why, you know, that guy with a big nose.